# Is it possible to execute SelectMainProgram/SelectScheduleProgram when NC Link is on?

Tags: c#, okuma

I'm working on automated workplace consisting of Okuma MC and a robot (robotic arm). There is System Link (aka NC Link) hardware switch on Okuma MC. The primary purpose of the switch (when switched on) is to enable the robot to partially control the MC.

When System Link is on, calling `SelectMainProgram`/`SelectScheduleProgram` ends with error: `5249 FMS coupling mode`

Is this behavior meant by design? If yes, do you have any suggestion how to overcome it?

It currently blocks us from controlling the Okuma MC from SCADA and at the same time use robotic arm to load/unload thing to/from the MC...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the appropriate place to be asking this question as it does not relate directly to programming.
However, yes. This is by design. Machines with Robot Loader Interface act as a slave to the robot when system link is on. Therefore you should find a way to command the robot in order to control the cell.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Originally I wanted to ask on GitHub, but finally I decided to use SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to call `SelectMainProgram`/`SelectScheduleProgram` even the NC Link is on - turn ON Machine user parameter(Robot) 7.NC OPERATION INTERLOCK IS MADE INEFFECTIVE

[image]